# Makefile $@ symbol with findstring

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
.c.o:
ifneq (, $(findstring FOO, $@))
    @echo "FOO"
endif
```

The only problem is this does not work if $@ (current file) contains the string "FOO" when it should be.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifneq` [conditional directives](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) are evaluated during the [reading phase](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) of processing Makefile. At this point `$@` isn't known yet.

Try this one, using [conditional function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions):

```
.c.o:
    @$(if $(findstring FOO,$@),echo "FOO")
```